Create a dynamic pivot like the example shown
This is my sample raw data:



Ref_date
Ref_source




6/12/2024
A


6/13/2024
A


6/14/2024
B


6/15/2024
B



How do I get an output that mirrors the following:
I'd like for it to be dynamic per year, month, qtr. The qtr must be aggregated like the month via a count.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Best not to post images of sample data.   Nobody like data entry.   Why would you override my edit?

Yes, you can; should you? Probably not. This is a presentation layer issue. SSRS and a Matrix, for example, would work fine.

What about Q1 and Q4?   If you want those included, then you would NOT need Dynamic SQL

I love data entry. In fact, here is a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/4oc8wjX_

@BartMcEndree A true unicorn!!!

Thank you all for the responses. I literally smiled when I saw this. I appreciate the feedback

Month and quarter counts by Ref_source
SELECT Ref_Source, year(Ref_date) as [Year], 
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Jan, 
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Feb ,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Mar,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Month(Ref_date) Between 1 AND 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q1,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Apr ,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as May ,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as June ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Month(Ref_date) Between 4 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q2,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as July ,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Aug ,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Sep,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Month(Ref_date) Between 7 AND 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q3,
     SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Oct, 
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Nov ,
    SUM(CASE Month(Ref_date) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Dec,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Month(Ref_date) Between 10 AND 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q4
FROM Example
GROUP BY ref_source, year(Ref_date)

fiddle



Ref_Source
Year
Jan
Feb
Mar
Q1
Apr
May
June
Q2
July
Aug
Sep
Q3
Oct
Nov
Dec
Q4




A
2024
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


B
2024
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0




I think you need to take year into account too, otherwise this happens.

@testing-ma-lady thanks. grouping by year added

Just another option using a PIVOT in concert with a CROSS APPLY and the result is a Full Year view or dbFiddle 
Select *
  From ( 
         SELECT A.Ref_source
               ,Year  = year(Ref_Date)
               ,B.*
          FROM YourTable A
          Cross Apply ( values ('Q'+datename(Quarter,Ref_Date),1)
                              ,(left(datename(month,Ref_Date),3),1)
                              ,('YTD',1)
                      ) B(Item,Value)
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(value) for item in ( [Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Q1]
                                 ,[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Q2]
                                 ,[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Q3]
                                 ,[Oct],[Nov],[Dec],[Q4]
                                 ,[YTD] )
                               ) pvt


How can we get Zeros instead of nulls?

@BartMcEndree Sure.  Take a peek at the final select.   I only went to Jun/Q2  https://dbfiddle.uk/pZFQ-IRl.  But, I'm sure you'll get the idea

In the general case for pivoting data, all SQL databases have a strict rule: you MUST know the number of columns in the results at query compile time, before looking at ANY data in the table. If you have to look at the data to know about your column headers, you will NOT be able to do this in one step in any database I know.
Instead, you have two options:

Build the query to support some reasonable maximum number of columns, filling in NULL or empty values on the right for places where you over-estimate and omitting data if you underestimate.

Build the query over three steps:

Run a query to tell you how many columns you need.
Use the results from step 1 to write a new query on the fly (using the technique from the other option)
Run the query from step 2.



There are no other work-arounds. Worse, these queries tend to be painful to write and maintain, and extremely slow to run, because you typically need an additional pass through the entire data set for every additional column or set of columns you need.
This will be a painful process, because what you're asking to do is a violation of the relational set theory principles underpinning all SQL databases. This means you'll often have better results pivoting the data in this way in your client code or reporting tool.

In this specific case, it looks like you might always expect the same number of results (within a specific calendar or fiscal year). That means we can sometimes find better alternatives. For this problem, you might be able to use conditional aggregation as a shortcut.
But again, in general, you should pivot the data for this kind of report on the client.
SELECT r.Ref_Source
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(r.Ref_date) = 6 THEN 1 END) [June]
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(r.Ref_Date) IN (4,5,6) THEN 1 END) [Qtr2]
    ,...
FROM RawData r
WHERE Year(r.Ref_Date) = 2024
GROUP BY r.Ref_Source

